# use extracted voc2012.tar tarfile as input to cnn model

Tags: python, object

tar dataset file as input to the convolution neural network using this code 
how use extracted tarfile as input to the network model as x_test ,y_test
x_train,y_train?

`import tarfile
     import os
     from keras.applications import vgg16
     import numpy as np
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     import matplotlib
     #data
     os.chdir ("C:/Users/hp/Downloads")
     os.listdir()
     tar=tarfile.open('VOC2012test.tar')
     test=tar.extractall()
     for tarinfo in tar:
     print(tarinfo.name, "is", tarinfo.size, "bytes in size and is", end="")
     if tarinfo.isreg():
     print("a regular file.")
     elif tarinfo.isdir():
      print("a directory.")
     else:
        print("something else.")
    tar2=tarfile.open('VOCtrainval_11-May-2012.tar')
    train=tar2.extractall()
    for tarinfo in tar2:
    print(tarinfo.name, "is", tarinfo.size, "bytes in size and is", end="")
    # The data, shuffled and split between train and test sets:
    (X_train, y_train)=train
    (X_test, y_test) = test`

i get this error

`File "<ipython-input-54-49cf9d1e879a>", line 1, in <module>
    (X_test, y_test) = test`

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`